# Datalogic Skorpio scanner javascript

Tags: barcode, barcode-scanner

We have a browser-based solution that we want to integrate with Datalogic scanners.

We will be using the locked down browser as our primary interface.

We've got as far as configuring the scanner and can confirm that it is decoding our Code 39 barcodes.

We've set up a test page that is supposed to take the scanned code and dump it in a text area.

The test page is

```
    <!doctype html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>TEST</title>

    <meta http-equiv="DL_Code_39" content="Enable">
    <meta http-equiv="DL_Scan" content="Javascript:ValidateInput()">
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    function ValidateInput(n){
        document.getElementById("sku").value+=";"+n;
    };
</script>
    </head>        
    <body>

    <form method="post" name="fTest">
        <textarea rows="5" cols="15" name="sku" id="sku"></textarea><br>
        <input type="submit" value="go">
    </form>

    </body>
    </html>
```

When we scan, the javascript call is firing, but returning undefined.

If we give the javascript function call a variable (something not done in the documentation) it does not fire

We must be missing something simple but there is no sample code in the DL documentation and google can find nothing else either.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I have always found javascript support to be flaky on Windows CE. I assume this is what the data logic scanner is running on?

I would normally configure the scanner to act as a keyboard, that way you can use standard html forms and handle the logic server side. I haven't got a Scorpio to test with but the Falcons have this ability under encoding options.

You can also set a prefix and suffix that the scanner will append to the scanned barcode. In your case it looks like this might be ';\n'

Comment: Hi - thanks for the response. Yes it is running CE but we must be missing something on how to pass the decoded scan data to the form.

How would having the scanner act as a keyboard change that?

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this on my own

The problem in this case is one of the reasons why developers drink too much.

The problem is the name of the example javascript function described in the documentation

This code works perfectly

```
    <!doctype html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>TEST</title>
        <meta http-equiv="DL_Triggers" content="Enable">
        <meta http-equiv="DL_Code_39" content="Enable">
        <meta http-equiv="DL_Scan" content="Javascript:PassSKU">
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function PassSKU(n){
                if (n === undefined) {
                      n = 0;
                } 
                document.getElementById("sku").value+=";"+n;
            };

        </script>

    </head>

    <body>

    <form method="post" name="fTest">
        <textarea rows="5" cols="20" name="sku" id="sku"></textarea><br>
        <input type="submit" value="go">
    </form>

    </body>
    </html>
```

The only thing I changed was to rename my function call from ValidateInput() (the function name given in the documentation which I copied and pasted) to PassSKU

So

```
    <meta http-equiv="DL_Scan" content="Javascript:ValidateInput">
```

This does not work

```
    <meta http-equiv="DL_Scan" content="Javascript:AnyOtherFunctionName">
```

This works fine

WHY this fixed the problem is a topic for another time.

Answer (score 0):

In case someone comes across this question while searching for information on getting a Datalogic scanner to work with a web form, I've posted a working solution here: [stackoverflow: "Datalogic Falcon X3 - Barcode Scanner"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29415757/datalogic-falcon-x3-barcode-scanner)