# Datalogic Falcon x3 development

Tags: windows

I have been trying to begin development for a 'Datalogic Falcon x3+' device, and have had no luck so far even getting started.

The device currently has Windows 2006 C.E installed, and it has the most up-to-date firmware possible.

After doing research I found very little information on this device - specifically to develop for it, and all I have found is from the official website some old documentation and the SDK, which requires Visual Studio 2008. I could only find Visual Studio 2008 Express, and had no luck using the SDK.

I found a few posts relating to this device on SO, however there were no details pertaining to my line of questioning.

Does anybody know how to develop for this device? Is there perhaps any other IDE's I could use, or does anyone know how to perhaps make a simple application without use of the SDK?

Answer (score 0):

You don't state clearly what kind of "development" you want to do. But a scanner is really just a replacement for a keyboard. That is, it scans a barcode and decodes it into a text string, then delivers the string <somewhere>. That text string could just as well have been hand entered by someone using a keyboard; the scanner just does it much more quickly and accurately.

So one solution, given in [another stackoverflow topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29415757/datalogic-falcon-x3-barcode-scanner), is to create a simple web form with a single input field to receive scanned data, then process the data on the back end (web server) with a PHP program, or any other CGI program of your choice.